# How to clean HTML tags using C#

Tags: c#, html

For example:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="aaa.asp?id=1"> I want to get this text </a>
    <div>
        <h1>this is my want!!</h1>
        <b>this is my want!!!</b>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the result is:

```
 I want to get this text 
this is my want!!
this is my want!!!
```

Comment: He basically wants to serialize the HTML it looks like... just strip all markup out and only be left with the data.

Comment: Not really relevant to the question, but something you should definitely know: closing tags have a "/" in them. For example, "<h1>this is my want!!</h1>" - note the "</h1>".

Comment: @Samir - I believe the point here is also to cater for malformed html - not just xhtml.

Comment: @Marc Gravell - Yes,that's the point

Comment: Use this link for your question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523913/remove-html-tags-from-string-including-nbsp-in-c-sharp/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove all HTML tags from a string without knowing which tags are in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153998/how-do-i-remove-all-html-tags-from-a-string-without-knowing-which-tags-are-in-it)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack):

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    string s = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body").InnerText;
```

Comment: HtmlDocument  has no constructors and the doesn't contain method LoadHtml() or property DocumentNode...I am trying this code in VC2010 can you help me please?

Comment: @Ahmy are you sure you are using the agility pack?

Comment: Ohhhhhhh! Excuse me sir i didn't include agility pack ref...thanks Marc

Comment: i have another problem when applying your code that the apersand(&),@nbsp,gt,and lt characters still exist and causing to me incorrect text how can i eliminate like these characters

Comment: Mr.Marc i have banned from asking question and this was latterly.. and when i read bout this error message i found that i didn't commit anything of ban rules how can i ask about my problem?? is it an ethical way?

Comment: @Ahmy I don't know your scenario, but meta.stackoverflow.com may have answers.

Answer (score 16):

Use this function...

```
public string Strip(string text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: A better regex is `<[^>]*>` as the `?` in that one makes it quite slow.

Comment: Ick, this question is repeated a lot across SO, and this same bad answer is repeated a lot, too. As I already said in another identical post: "You shouldn't use a regular expression to parse a context-free grammar like HTML. If the HTML is being provided by some external entity, then it can be easily manipulated to evade your regular expression."

Comment: @mehaase, I use this parse in some codes until that day (mar/2013).
But actually I use the library "HtmlAgilityPack".

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using something like [HTMLTidy.](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2008/02/14/using-htmltidy-to-clean-up-html-with-c/) on it to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to make it server side?

For that you have to make the container element `runat="server"` and then take the `innerText` of the element.

You can do the same in javascript without making the element runat="server"

Comment: I am developing a news system, I would like to interception as a summary of some news content displayed in the Home

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the html tags then use a regular expression that deletes anything between "<" and ">".

Comment: I am a bit worried about the regex is so slow

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this simple function below. *Disclaimer: This code is suitable for basic HTML, but will not handle all valid HTML situations and edge cases. Tags within quotes is an example.* The advantage of this code is you can easy follow the execution in a debugger, and it can be easy modified to fit edge cases specific to you.

```
public static string RemoveTags(string html)
    {
        string returnStr = "";
        bool insideTag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < html.Length; ++i)
        {
            char c = html[i];
            if (c == '<')    
                insideTag = true;
            if (!insideTag)
                returnStr += c;
            if (c == '>')         
                insideTag = false;
        }
        return returnStr;        
    }
```

Comment: This is basically just an unrolled version of the regex answer above, and as such it's not any more robust. This would easily be thrown off, for example, by a quoted attribute that contains a ">", not to mention a pathological case like the one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175840/is-html-a-context-free-language.

Comment: Will it pass `<div title="x<4>" id="vectorizer"> text here <img class="foo"> text there</div>`?

Comment: @Annie Unfortunately it will not work with tags contained within quotes as is. You could modify it to catch those types of edge cases.