# How can I strip html tags in C#

Tags: c#, .net, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clean HTML tags using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038431/how-to-clean-html-tags-using-c)

What is the best way to strip HTML tags in C#?

Comment: Do you know which tags you want to strip? Or is it all? Even if the html tags change in the future do you still want the code to work? Will the input always be valid XHTML?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/asp-net-strip-html-tags and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038431/how-to-clean-html-tags-using-c

Answer (score 29):

```
  public static string StripHTML(string htmlString)
  {

     string pattern = @"<(.|\n)*?>";

     return Regex.Replace(htmlString, pattern, string.Empty);
  }
```

Comment: my pleasure, at your service, mam

Comment: Ick, this question is repeated a lot across SO, and this same bad answer is repeated a lot, too. As I already said in another identical post: "You shouldn't use a regular expression to parse a context-free grammar like HTML. If the HTML is being provided by some external entity, then it can be easily manipulated to evade your regular expression."

Comment: we're using htmlagilitypack now

Comment: it depends what you want to achieve. HAP might be extremely slow to strip effectively a few millions of short strings when quality is not required.

Comment: Removing tag by css class name string cssClassName = "myCSSClass"; string pattern = String.Format("<div[^>]+class=([""'])[^>]*{0}[^>]*\1[^>]*>(.|\n)*?</div>", cssClassName); Regex.Replace(htmlString, pattern, string.Empty);

Comment: Great answer, I have stolen it to post in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67812771/15920836

Answer (score 7):

Take your HTML string or document and parse it with [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack). This will give you a HTMLDocument object that is very similar to a XmlDocument.

You can then use it's methods such as `SelectNodes` to access those portions of the document that you are interested in.

If you choose to use another approach, be aware that parsing HTML (a non-Regular language) with Regular Expressions is widely regarded as [a bad idea](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

And regardless of the approach, if you are keeping some markup, use a whitelist approach. This means to remove everything that is not explicitly wanted.

Comment: HTML Agility Pack saved me one day. +1

Comment: What if it's not a well-formed document at all? For instance just a bunch of text with one tag somewhere inside, will Agility Pack parse that for you?

Comment: @EgorPavlikhin yes, and it will fix the invalid markup and make a valid html document.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that you shouldn't parse a CFG with a regular expression. I would +100 you if I could.

Answer (score 1):

To guarantee that no HTML tags get through, use: [`HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(string);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx).

If you want *some* to get through, you can use this ["Whitelist" approach](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html).

Update: There has been some vulnerabilities found in that code; as a [Developer from Fog Creek tells us](http://danlec.com/blog/hacking-stackoverflow-com-s-html-sanitizer).

(Second link includes code).

Comment: HTMLEncode("The image tag: <img>")) %> Output: The image tag: &lt;img&gt which is not the same as Strip it.

Comment: It all depends on the result he wants. If he wants to make sure that no HTML tags are ever executed (and thus open himself up to XSS), than the first way is the 'best' way. If he just wants to have plaintext come through, a variation of the second way is 'best'.

Comment: He might want to remove tags to display it as clear text in an rss-feed or something. In PHP you have a built in funciton called http://php.net/strip_tags which of the sound of it is what he wants. But the whitelist solves that, you could also use that HTML Pack or whatever it is called..

Comment: Actually, this approach is FAR more secure than the regex suggested above. The only drawback to this approach is that user's may not want to see encoded HTML.

Comment: Links in answers are a bad idea because they sometimes break!

Comment: While interesting, it answers a different question, as it does not strip HTML tags.