# Finding first Image from a content

Tags: asp.net, image, methods, find

How can I find an image from a content? I have a method in aspx I am calling this method for remove all html tags like this: `Usage.DeleteHtml(Eval("content").ToString())`

but I don't want delete img tag from content.. I should find the first image I will show it on my page.. like this:`<a href="#"><img src="Usage.FindImage("content")" /></a>`

but couldn't write  a method for finding image..

my DeleteHtml method:

```
public static string DeleteHtml(string text)
{
    string mystr= Regex.Replace(text, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
    return mystr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your task is essentially retrieving the first image in document.
If your HTML document is a well-formed XML-document as well, you could easily solve your task using XPath.

More on XPath in .NET [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333).

XPath query to retrieve the first image's URL will look like this:

```
//img[1]/@src
```

Otherwise, if you really need to strip HTML, it's a duplicate to a couple of questions already:

[Using C# regular expressions to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)

[How can I strip HTML tags from a string in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785715/how-can-i-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-asp-net)

[How to clean HTML tags using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038431/how-to-clean-html-tags-using-c)

Short answer: use Html Agility Pack.