# How to parse the text out of html in c#

Tags: c#, html, xml, parsing

I have an html expression like this:

```
 "This is <h4>Some</h4> Text" + Environment.NewLine +
 "This is some more <h5>text</h5>
```

And I want only to extract the text. So the result should be

```
"This is Some Text" + Environment.NewLine +
 "This is some more text"
```

How do I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038431/how-to-clean-html-tags-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

```
string html = @"This is <h4>Some</h4> Text" + Environment.NewLine +
                "This is some more <h5>text</h5>";

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var str = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple using regex: `Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty);`

Comment: Regex can be problematic. Try for ex, this `<h4 title='e>Sh<opping'>it happens</h4>`

Comment: Yes, that's true, I'd actually wouldn't recommend using regex everywhere for everything (and use somebody else's tested solution). Still - for simpler cases such regex would be enough.

Comment: Yes ;) my regex would work well on properly escaped xhtml, but I get your point. My answer was not about general solution (as was yours), but solution that would be enough for specific cases.