# regular expression to eliminate text inside < and >

Tags: c#, html, regex, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using C# regular expressions to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)

I'm trying to write a code that will return only the content of an HTML file. The best way I've figured revolves either around eliminating all elements within < ..> brackets, or to make a list of all text in between >...< brackets. I'm pretty new to regular expressions, but I'm pretty sure they're the way to go.

Here's the code I've tried

```
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"<.*>");
        file = reg.Replace(file, "");
```

Which works, as long as there is only one <...> before a block of text. Any file that has two or more of those elements in sequence, like <...><...>, and it just starts deleting any text it finds. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just try the test string in the comment. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12510496/932418

Comment: .*? will work like charm. unless you want something else to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Regex are regulary greedy (they match the longest string they can find). Try checking, depending on the language you are looking for, for the +? or *? operators, that will try the shortest match. Otherwise you must build another regex.

Comment: THanks, I'll read up more on greediness.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the unexpected behavior you're getting is because your regular expression is greedy

If you change your regex to

```
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"<.*?>");
    file = reg.Replace(file, "");
```

you'll get what you expect.

Also, Know that Regex doesn't handle nesting, which HTML has a lot of, and I'd avoid using Regex to parse HTML unless you're trying to match a very specific thing, on a specifically formed piece of html.

Comment: Thanks. Should I use HTML agility pack instead? I saw that referenced in a comment.

Comment: @Sam what does your code give for `<h4 title='e>Sh<opping'>it happens</h4>` ?

Comment: @GeorgeAbrahamSiegelDuffy  I've never really had to parse HTML myself, but I would definitely have a look at it.  if you need to parse HTML.

Comment: @L.B  It renders "shit happens"  you've made that comment/linked to that comment 3 times at least in this single thread.  Stop being a broken record, and also read the answer you're replying to

Comment: @Sam  When you stop trying to parse html with regex, i will stop giving the same reference.

Comment: @L.B for crying out loud, get over yourself

Comment: Actually, I was trying to figure out a way to ignore things like <strong> so a phrase wouldn't be broken up by a bolded word, so the shit happens problem kinda counts towards my advantage.

Comment: @GeorgeAbrahamSiegelDuffy  LB's example is a Header formatted text, who's `title` attribute is `'e>Sh<opping'`  what it actually renders is `it happens` thus my comment that you have to be doing something very specific to a specific piece of html for regex to work correctly