# How to copy html text selection and assign it to a string in c#

Tags: c#, html, copy, selection, office-interop

I have an .html file containing only text(formatted somehow).I am wondering if there is a way to copy all of the text(like if would do with ctrl+A) and assign it to a string So I can then export it to .txt file ? All this must happen from the code-behind(opening the html, selecting the text and assigning it to a string).

In the `Microsoft.Office.Interop` I remember that there was an option for copying the active window selection or something, so I was wondering if this is possible and here.

Comment: if html(?) contains only text, why don't you open file and get it's text and assign it to string? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ezwyzy7b.aspx

Comment: Or just rename the html file to a txt file? (or copy)

Comment: Do you mean explicit converting from html to txt ?

Comment: "an .html file containing only text" - well, that's what all `.html` files are... do you mean "[remove all tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038431/how-to-clean-html-tags-using-c-sharp)"?

Comment: @Corak I mean after loaded in a browser it contains text only.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik - Okay, so if you follow the provided [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1038531/1336590), Marc Gravells answer should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use [HttpAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Someone could say it's overblown, but otherwise tomorrow you'll ask us how to convert the &code; that are in the file, and the next day you'll ask something else.

Answer (score 0):

use this for read from file

```
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.html"))
        {
            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx

and this for read from url

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://test.com/file.html");
```