# Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment("<b>Table</b>") return table in the bold style

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to this function only return Table. but the problem is that this return Table in Bold style.

```
string Name="<b>Table</b>";
string newName = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(Name);
```

Comment: Did you try to solve it with a Regular Expression like `"<b>(.*?)</b>"`  ?

Comment: No i just want to remove Html tag when submited to the server. @MrMAG

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clean HTML tags using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038431/how-to-clean-html-tags-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Implement `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

```
string Name = "<b>Table</b>";

Regex regex = new Regex("<b>(.*?)</b>"); 
Name = regex.Match(Name).Groups[1].ToString();
// Name = Table (without <b>-Tags)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wants to handle more than just `<b>` tags. Those were just an example.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the correct use of the AntiXss library.  It's designed to prevent script injections.  So when you call

```
GetSafeHtmlFragment("<b>Table</b>")
```

it's returning the entire string because it determines there is nothing unsafe about it, which of course is correct.

If you want to make sure a string is safe against script injections, then the AntiXss library is the way to go.  It won't remove html tags that are harmless, just ones that pose a threat.

If you want to remove ALL html tags, whether they are safe or not, then a regex is the way to go as discussed here:
[Regular expression to remove HTML tags from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229831/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string)

```
String justTheText = textAndHtml.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```