# SQL and SSRS - Remove all HTML tags in a string and search plain text

Tags: html, xml, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008

I have a varchar field which stores content from a wysiwyg editor so it contains html markup. I need to be able to search by keyword for a SSRS report.

I have the following which seems to work if the html is properly formed but if not then it throws xml parsing error.

```
XML parsing: line 1, character 55, well formed check: undeclared entity
```

Is there a way in sql server to strip all html and search only the plain text or any other suggestion how I can achieve this i.e. a query to search for keywords from this column?

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Subject, t1.Details
FROM Tickets AS t1 
 WHERE (CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(t1.Details, '>', '/>'), '</', '<') AS XML).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%' OR t1.Subject LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%')
```

As a workaround I've tried to add the filter inside SSRS as follows but if I search for keyword `<span>` it is still returning results for some odd reason?

```
 =(Fields!Description.Value Like "*" + Parameters!keyword.Value + "*") Or ( System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Fields!Description.Value, "<[^>]+>","") Like  "*" + Parameters!keyword.Value + "*");
```

Why is the regex filter not working?

Comment: possible duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868364/sql-remove-all-html-tags-in-a-string

Comment: [Here are some UDFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457701/best-way-to-strip-html-tags-from-a-string-in-sql-server) that can do it, but for reporting the performance of any approach like this will be absolutely  dreadful.  It may be better to derive a text copy of the html at the point of insertion/update and then base your searches on that. Deriving text from html is likely also going to be much easier/reliable in your client language.