# How to remove HTML from a field using a SQL query and not a function

Tags: html, sql

Want to remove HTML tags etc. from a field using a SQL query.  There are great posts that use a function.  We do not have permissions to create a function, is there anyway we can do it in the SQL query?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868364/sql-remove-all-html-tags-in-a-string/38868776

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - Remove all HTML tags in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868364/sql-remove-all-html-tags-in-a-string)

Comment: I not understand how to add it to the SQL Query [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868364/sql-remove-all-html-tags-in-a-string

Comment: Are you on SQL Server 2017+?

Comment: yes, the latest