# Get content block without HTML

Tags: c#, sitefinity, sitefinity-10

Is there a **built-in Sitefinity method** for displaying blog post content without the HTML? *NO*T the standard standalone C# methodology, but a **built-in method in Sitefinity** so I can avoid duplicating functionality.

**A built in method in Sitefinity, not a generic C# solution.**

I'd like to show a summary from my content rather than the separate summary field. I'm in my custom blog list .cshtml file, doing this to retrieve content:

```
Html.Raw(item.Fields.Content).ToString()
```

Which gives me the content, but I need to display with without the HTML tags a user may have added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clean HTML tags using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038431/how-to-clean-html-tags-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @ZoharPeled No, since this is asking for a built-in method in a specific application.

Comment: there is no build in method

Comment: @Steve if you're certain, please post that as the answer :)

Comment: Well, I've never even known there is such a thing as sitefinity until I saw this question, but if your goal is to remove html tags from a string, then the accepted answer for the question I've linked to will do it. In my book, that qualifies as a duplicate.

Comment: @ZoharPeled that does not meet the definition of duplicate. IF this SPECIFIC application has built-in methodology to return its content object without HTML tags, I'd like to know. If the OP mentions a specific application and the tags are for a specific application, but you didn't even know the application existed, your response is inappropriate. It's annoying that the C# community knee-jerks with "duplicate" for even remotely related questions that end up not being helpful or relevant to the OP.

Comment: Again. You wrote in your question that you "...need to display with without the HTML tags..." - and you tagged [c#]. I've pointed you to a question on how to remove HTML tags using [c#]. So it's not built in to your cms of choice, so what? It does what you asked for, and it's relevant since you are using the same language as in the other question. I'm sorry, but I really still think it's a valid duplicate. You may find it annoying that the C# community marks a lot of questions as duplicates, but I'll bet I'm not the only c# developer that finds it annoying that people ask before searching.

Comment: @ZoharPeled "built-in Sitefinity method" - don't assume I didn't search. I always search.

Comment: Whatever. To me it seems that getting the desired result is more important then what tools you use to get them. Insisting on a method built in sitefinity doesn't strike me as more important then getting the result you want, but hey, it's your question, not mine. You think my duplicate vote is wrong, I think it's right. Sometimes people just don't agree with each other, and that's perfectly fine. Anyway, I I'm done arguing over this. I will not revoke my duplicate vote, even if you think it's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If you refer `using Telerik.Sitefinity.Utilities` you will get an extension method `StripHtmlTags` for the `string` type.

This is a public extension method and you should not have problems using it.

Answer (score 1):

I see there are a few classes in Sitefinity that do HTML stripping:

**public static HtmlStripper** in Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Newsletters.Composition namespace.

and

**internal static class HtmlStripper** in Telerik.Sitefinity.Utilities.HtmlParsing namespace, which seems to be the one you need, because it has a StripHtml method, but you cannot use it as it is internal.

I agree with @Zohar that in this particular case you should just use a standard C# approach - you cannot go wrong with it.